# Node.js Express can't call api with route parameter before static path

Tags: node.js, api, express

```
app.get('/api/post/:postId/photos', function(req, res) { 
  ...
});
```

I want to call an API with this format but postman returned `404` not found with `localhost:5000/api/post/123/photos`. Can anyone help?

Comment: which method did you use ? POST or GET ?

Comment: can you share you full routes config for express? It might be that your 404 error handler is placed before the one in the question